# Show/Hide keyboard when swipe on screen like imessenger provides

Tags: ios, ios7, keyboard, swipe

I want to implement , when swipe bottom to top of screen the keyboard is shown on screen and when swipe from top to bottom on screen the keyboard hides.
Its like iOS 7 effect when we swipe on screen the search textfield and keyboard is shown and when swipe down its hide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
//declare a property to store your current responder
@property (nonatomic, assign) id currentResponder;
//in viewDidLoad:

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resignOnSwipe:)];
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];


//Implement the below delegate method:

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.currentResponder = textField;
}

//Implement resignOnSwipe:

- (void)resignOnSwipe:(id)sender {
    [self.currentResponder resignFirstResponder]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this,.. It works fine

In xib,

Add a textfield and hide it. Connect that to your .h file and name it as tf.

In .h file,

Add

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface KeyboardDisplay : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
```

__weak IBOutlet UITextField *tf;

```
}
```

In .m file,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture2 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
swipeGesture2.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture2];

}

-(void)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender
{

//Gesture detect - swipe up/down , can be recognized direction
if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)
{

    [tf becomeFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"Up");

}
else if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)
{

    [tf resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"down");
}
}
```

NOTE : Don't forget to hide the textfield in xib.